# gulp-watch plugin doesn't trigger on new files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I read that watch function delivered with `gulp` package doesn't trigger on new files (and indeed it didn't). But then I read somewhere that it should work fine with `gulp-watch` plugin. So I did install it and set up my `gulpfile` but still the same thing, it dosen't run tasks whenever I put new files.

(gruntfile.js)

```
function gulpTemplates() {
  return gulp.src(path.templates)
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/templates'));
}

...

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  watch(path.components, gulpBower);
  watch(path.index, gulpJade);
  watch(path.templates, gulpTemplates);
  watch(path.styles, gulpSass);
  watch(path.scripts, function () {
    gulpLint();
    gulpJs();
  });
});
```

Is that even possible to make it happen, to `gulp-watch` plugin watch for new files?

Answer (score 1):

Ive been using Gulp for a couple of year now and never found an issue to this. When you run Gulp, during its compilation it takes note of the existing files and watches them only. A newly added file is not in Gulps memory, therefore it struggles to 'watch' new files... Being able to watch a folder would be a better choice.